# How do I get more comments from facebook?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have written a small python script to parse comments from facebook posts. But when I do my call via their graph API:

`graph.get_object(user_id+"_"+post_id+"/comments")`

I only get like 20 comments, from a post with like 5000 comments. Is it possible to retreive more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass a parameter `limit` such as `/comments?limit=500`.

Otherwise, you also should be getting a `paging` object in the response which contains `cursors` values which allow for pagination to make another request in order to get the next comments. You even get a field `next` with the query you need to make in order to get the next page of results.

```
"paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "beforeCursorValue",
      "after": "afterCursorValue"
    },
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/..."
  }
```

Comment: Summery and filter does not help me though? Also this does not make it retrieve more comments. Since it will only execute the parameters on the retreived comments.

Comment: @FelixRosén cool, you should mark the question as answered then

Comment: Yes, will do. Just curious. Is it possible to get the maximum amount of comments? Like setting the limit to ´none´ or something?

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing, if you want to get all the results. Best solution would be to make use of the values in `paging`.